# Out of memory error on MS Access Project

Tags: vba, ms-access, adp

I work on MS Access VBA project (ADP) .. Recently I faced a problem that when save the code I got "out of memory" error or when made any changes the compile or editor (I DON'T KNOW) delete the line that I tried to edit (sometimes when change variable name automatically its name changed to **Me**).

Knowing that I google it and find these sources but it didn't help

[Out of memory link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396998/how-to-clear-memory-to-prevent-out-of-memory-error-in-excel-vba)

[Out of memory link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/out-of-memory-visual-basic-compiler-error)

[Out of memory link 3](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/performance/decompile.asp)

(Same problem with access 2003 and 2010)

Is there any way to trace or get compiler logs to check where and what the actual problem is (just like some compilers do for example visual studio or eclipse)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like corruption. Try a full [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271).

Comment: I treid that .. it works for half or one hour changes and then the same problem occurs again

Comment: Did you do every single step listed in that answer? Steps 3-6 are essential.

Comment: No .. I did what @Tim Lentine's said .. I will try the steps you mentioned and I hope that help.

Comment: @Andre Thank you .. I tried and it works now but I will test the project for two days or a week and tell you the result.

Comment: @Andre - good suggestion and recommendation. I personally find the decompile, compact and compile steps essential before I distribute new updates to clients when using complex databases with lots of code and parameter queries.

Comment: @Andre - Unfortunately, the error occurred again. I find out that the code reached the maximum limitations, when I try to add just one Public Function the problem happened, I think I have to reduce some public code to ignore limitations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa240819(v=vs.60)

Comment: You may want to move some code into an external "library" database. This seems like a good explanation: https://www.devhut.net/2017/11/14/ms-access-library-databases/

Comment: @Andre Thank you very much and I hope this way works for MS Access Project "ADP"