# High Memory utilization issue during vba extraction

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, data-extraction

I am using below mentioned code for data extraction,this code is working fine for me when java scripts are disabled in Internet Explorer but when i enable scripts then Memory utilization is very high and increase after each url extraction.Suggestion require so that system will use very low memory.I use following code i.e set ie=nothing or ie.refresh2 but still same issue.

[image]

```
Ie.navigate url1234
Do While Ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or _
Ie.Busy = True
DoEvents
Loop
Set html = Ie.Document
html1 = html.body.innerHTML
```

Comment: anyone have some idea?

Comment: What's an example url? And what is your system set-up?

Comment: example url is "www.amazon.com/dp/B07KVVKQ9T" and as for concern of system i am using vps.thanks.

Comment: did you check above link?

Comment: I test on a vm and the memory usage will be a little higher when script is enabled because running scripts also need to use memory. But it's just a little higher than script is disabled, I don't see it's very high. Could you explain more detailly how high it is in your scenario? It could be better if you can provide a screenshot of the issue. Besides, don't forget to add `IE.Quit`, `Set IE = Nothing` when you finish the automation.

Comment: Actually if we have urls in thousands for extraction then with the passage to time Memory and CPU utilization is very high and finally almost not responding.

Comment: I think it's reasonable that the Memory and CPU utilization is high when you're operating **thousands of urls**. It also be related with your vps configuration. If you need to work with thousands of urls in vba, I think you need a high configuration and high performance vps. Besides, try to optimize your code to avoid operating all the urls at a time.

Comment: But why no high usage without enabling scripting?

Comment: Because executing scripts needs to use Memory and CPU. If you disable scripting, it will save a lot of Memory and CPU usage especially you're operating thousands of urls.

Comment: so Is this possible that after each request all usage will be cleared,I use set html=nothing etc but usage is same.thanks.

Comment: `Set obj = Nothing` seems not always work. I have no other ideas, but for clearing memory methods, you can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396998/how-to-clear-memory-to-prevent-out-of-memory-error-in-excel-vba).